# connect to Apple Watch through node.js

Tags: node.js, api, apple-watch

I am looking to try to connect a workout from my Apple Watch to my node.js application. I am not using react or anything, I just specifically want to connect to the Apple Watch through node.js and grab the data.

Is it possible through an Api, without using swift?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any API provided by apple to use it in your React app. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/).